# Deleted item in redux store array not reflected correctly in react UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having an issue with my input forms displaying the correct information after I delete one. The ComponentInput.js (basically a form) components manage the state of their child inputs/dropdown selections using a useReducer function. Within a useEffect call, the redux store is updated once the user has filled out all of the inputs. The forms are displayed (using a carousel) by mapping the components array in the redux store.

When I delete one of the forms ('case DELETE_COMPONENT' in reducer.js using a componentStateHandler function found in helpers.js), the correct item is removed from the components array in the redux store, however the UI does not correctly reflect that deletion and appears to remove the last item in the array. (I tried using object references rather than array indexing and was still experiencing the same issue).

Example of the issue below. I have attached the code for the redux store, helper functions (can view how state is acted upon in this file), and the Parent(Carousel.js)/Child(ComponentInputs.js) components in question.

```
//Issue
const componentsOnScreen = [<ComponentInput dataInReducer={{ name: 'Mike' }} />, <ComponentInput dataInReducer={{ name: 'Sarah' }} />, <ComponentInput dataInReducer={{ name: 'James' }} />]

const dataInStore = [{ name: 'Mike' }, { name: 'Sarah' }, { name: 'James' }]

//call delete function to remove Sarah using array index
const componentsOnScreen = [<ComponentInput dataInReducer={{ name: 'Mike' }} />, <ComponentInput dataInReducer={{ name: 'Sarah' }} />]

const dataInStore = [{ name: 'Mike' }, { name: 'James' }]
```

One fix was to set the initial useReducer state to the data stored within the components array in the redux store that is mapped over in order to display a form to the UI. The problem now is that the "update the store" function in the useEffect is called twice.

Thoughts? Thanks much.

**Carousel.js**

```
import React, { Children } from 'react'
import ComponentInput from './ComponentInput.component'
import { PlaceholderIcons } from './PlaceholderIcons.component';
import { ControlledCarousel } from '../common/ControlledCarousel.component';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getComponents } from '../../redux/selectors';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    carousel: {
        width: '800px'
    }
}))

const MixComponentCarousel = ({ letter, newSlideIndex, components }) => {

    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <Box className={classes.carousel}>
            <ControlledCarousel
                dots={false}
                newSlideIndex={newSlideIndex}
            >
                {
                    components.length !== 0 ?
                        Children.toArray(components.map((componentProps, i) => {
                            return <ComponentInput
                                id={`solution_${i}`}
                                index={i}
                                letter={letter}
                                componentProps={componentProps}
                            />
                        }
                        )) : <PlaceholderIcons />
                }
            </ControlledCarousel>
        </Box>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const { solutionMixReducer } = state
    const { letter } = ownProps
    const components = getComponents(solutionMixReducer, letter)
    return {
        components
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MixComponentCarousel)
```

**ComponentInput.js**

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { BottomRightInputs } from './bottom_input_sections/bottom-right-inputs.section.jsx'
import { BottomLeftInputs } from './bottom_input_sections/bottom-left-inputs.section';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { updateComponent } from '../../redux/actions/actions';

const ComponentInput = (props) => {

    const {
        index,
        letter,
        updateComponent,
        componentProps
    } = props

    const [inputFocused, setInputFocused] = useState(false)

    const [inputs, dispatch] = useReducer((state = componentProps, action) => {
        return {
            ...state,
            [action.name]: action.value,
        }
    })

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target

        dispatch({
            value: value,
            name: name,
        })
    }

    const handleInputFocusChange = () => {
        setInputFocused(prev => !prev)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (inputs) {
            const entries = Object.entries(inputs)
            if (entries.length === 6) {
                if (!inputFocused) {
                    updateComponent(letter, inputs, index)
                }
            }
        }
    }, [inputs, componentProps, updateComponent, letter, index])

    return (
        <Box
            display='flex'
        >
            <BottomLeftInputs
                handleChange={handleChange}
                setInputFocused={handleInputFocusChange}
            />
            <BottomRightInputs />
        </Box>
    )
}

export default connect(
    null,
    { updateComponent }
)(ComponentInput)
```

**reducer.js**

```
import { ADD_MIX, DELETE_MIX, ADD_COMPONENT, DELETE_COMPONENT, UPDATE_COMPONENT } from '../actions/actionTypes'
import { addMix, deleteMix, componentStateHandler } from './helpers'

const randomColor = require('randomcolor');

const initialState = {
    letterCount: 1,
    solutionMixes: [
        {
            letter: 'A',
            color: randomColor(),
            components: []
        }
    ]
}

const solutionMixReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MIX:
            return addMix(state)
        case DELETE_MIX:
            return deleteMix(state, action.payload)
        case ADD_COMPONENT:
            return componentStateHandler(state, action)
        case DELETE_COMPONENT:
            return componentStateHandler(state, action)
        case UPDATE_COMPONENT:
            return componentStateHandler(state, action)
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export { solutionMixReducer }
```

**helpers.js**

```
import { ADD_COMPONENT, UPDATE_COMPONENT, DELETE_COMPONENT } from '../actions/actionTypes'
const randomColor = require('randomcolor');

const generateLetter = (n) => {
    const chr = String.fromCharCode(97 + n)
    return chr.toUpperCase()
}

const addMix = (state) => {

    const newLetter = generateLetter(state.letterCount)

    const newSolutionMix = {
        title: `Master Mix ${newLetter}`,
        letter: newLetter,
        color: randomColor(),
        components: []
    }

    return {
        ...state,
        letterCount: state.letterCount + 1,
        solutionMixes: [...state.solutionMixes, newSolutionMix]
    }
}

const deleteMix = (state, letter) => {
    if (state.solutionMixes.length !== 1) {
        const filtered = state.solutionMixes.filter(item => item.letter !== letter)
        return { ...state, solutionMixes: filtered }
    }
    return state
}

const componentActionHandler = (action, mix) => {
    let modification = ''
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_COMPONENT:
            modification = [...mix.components, {}]
            break
        case DELETE_COMPONENT:
            modification = mix.components.filter((_, i) => i !== action.payload.index)
            break
        case UPDATE_COMPONENT:
            modification = mix.components.map((comp, i) => i === action.payload.index ? action.payload.component : comp)
            break
        default:
            break;
    }
    return modification
}

const componentStateHandler = (state, action) => {

    return {
        ...state,
        solutionMixes: state.solutionMixes.map(mix =>
            mix.letter === action.payload.letter ?
                {
                    ...mix,
                    components: componentActionHandler(action, mix)
                }
                : mix
        )
    }
}

export { addMix, deleteMix, componentStateHandler }
```

Comment: Show us the code as to how you are deleting in the reducer, you're most likely doing redux wrong and mutating state rather than returning new state.

Comment: @Adam The 'helpers.js' image attached shows this --> case DELETE_COMPONENT.

Comment: Yes, perhaps your `deleteMix` is mutating state, as Adam as alluded to.

Comment: @Adam The deletion of the forms is handled in reducer.js under 'case DELETE_COMPONENT'. The function being called 'componentStateHandler()' can be found in helpers.js. Apologies if that was not clear. I've seen cases of people pasting code or using images. Did you by chance mean to say something more explicit like "paste the code so we can perhaps recreate the issues."? Can do that if it would help.